# Evenly spread time in MySQL table with PHP Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will go through a SQL table containing products that are being auctioned on my site.

To update each item's end time in such a way that the end times for all products are spaced out evenly.

For example,

- if all items are to be closed on Friday, between 12:00pm and 22:00pm (i.e. 10 hours or 600 minutes),
- and I have 600 items that week,

I would like there to be 1 minute in between each item's end time.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","DB User","DB Password","DB Table Name");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$starttime = "2015-07-06 12:00:00";
$endtime = "2015-07-06 22:00:00";
$nProducts = "600";
$timeinterval = ($endtime-$starttime)/$nProducts;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Products";     

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$revisedtime = $starttime;

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sqlupdate = "UPDATE Products SET end_time = " . $revisedtime . " WHERE id = " . $row["id"];
        mysqli_query($con, $sqlupdate);
        $revisedtime = $revisedtime + $timeinterval;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

When I ran this script the first item's end_time was changed to **"2015-07-06 12:00:00"** but every other item's end time was changed to **"0000-00-00 00:00:00"** for some reason...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe your problem is with `$timeinterval = ($endtime-$starttime)/$nProducts;`. You can't subtract stings like that. You'll need to convert it to a timestamp (integer) first, and then do math with it.

Comment: I meant *strings, ha.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I changed the line to $timeinterval = (strtotime($endtime)-strtotime($starttime))/$nProducts;
and it worked :)